# having issue importing tensorflow module in windows

Tags: python-3.x, tensorflow

> > > import tensorflow
> > >       Traceback (most recent call last):
> > >         File "D:\python36\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\pywrap_tensorflow_internal.py", line 18, in swig_import_helper
> > >           fp, pathname, description = imp.find_module('_pywrap_tensorflow_internal', [dirname(**file**)])
> > >         File "D:\python36\lib\imp.py", line 296, in find_module
> > >           raise ImportError(_ERR_MSG.format(name), name=name)
> > >       ImportError: No module named '_pywrap_tensorflow_internal'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:\python36\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\pywrap_tensorflow.py", line 58, in 
    from tensorflow.python.pywrap_tensorflow_internal import *
  File "D:\python36\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\pywrap_tensorflow_internal.py", line 28, in 
    _pywrap_tensorflow_internal = swig_import_helper()
  File "D:\python36\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\pywrap_tensorflow_internal.py", line 20, in swig_import_helper
    import _pywrap_tensorflow_internal
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named '_pywrap_tensorflow_internal'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "", line 1, in 
  File "D:\python36\lib\site-packages\tensorflow__init__.py", line 24, in 
    from tensorflow.python import pywrap_tensorflow  # pylint: disable=unused-import
  File "D:\python36\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python__init__.py", line 49, in 
    from tensorflow.python import pywrap_tensorflow
  File "D:\python36\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\pywrap_tensorflow.py", line 74, in 
    raise ImportError(msg)
ImportError: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:\python36\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\pywrap_tensorflow_internal.py", line 18, in swig_import_helper
    fp, pathname, description = imp.find_module('_pywrap_tensorflow_internal', [dirname(**file**)])
  File "D:\python36\lib\imp.py", line 296, in find_module
    raise ImportError(_ERR_MSG.format(name), name=name)
ImportError: No module named '_pywrap_tensorflow_internal'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:\python36\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\pywrap_tensorflow.py", line 58, in 
    from tensorflow.python.pywrap_tensorflow_internal import *
  File "D:\python36\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\pywrap_tensorflow_internal.py", line 28, in 
    _pywrap_tensorflow_internal = swig_import_helper()
  File "D:\python36\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\pywrap_tensorflow_internal.py", line 20, in swig_import_helper
    import _pywrap_tensorflow_internal
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named '_pywrap_tensorflow_internal'

Failed to load the native TensorFlow runtime.

See https://www.tensorflow.org/install/errors

for some common reasons and solutions.  Include the entire stack trace
above this error message when asking for help.

Comment: Does your CPU support AVX instructions? If yes then have you installed Microsoft Redistributable C++ 2015 Update 3?

Comment: Yes, I have installed Microsoft Redistributable C++ 2015 Update 3 both x64 and x86, but still error is there.

Comment: Is there AVX support?

Comment: could u tell me how to check for that?

Comment: Refer this [article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Advanced_Vector_Extensions) and see whether your processor is mentioned under AVX support.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**1.** **Use Anaconda**

[Anaconda](https://www.anaconda.com) uses conda distribution index which is similar to PyPI. The TensorFlow conda build uses [MKL ( Intel Math Kernel Library )](https://software.intel.com/en-us/mkl). It works without AVX.

Download Anaconda as mentioned [here](https://docs.anaconda.com/anaconda/install/windows/) and create a new conda enviroment as mentioned [here](https://docs.conda.io/projects/conda/en/latest/user-guide/tasks/manage-environments.html).

Run this command:

```
conda install tensorflow
```

**2. Use builds from [tensorflow-windows-wheel](https://github.com/fo40225/tensorflow-windows-wheel) repo.**

This repo contains a number of TensorFlow pip wheel files which are build using SSE instead of AVX. SSE build run without any compilation errors. Use this [file](https://github.com/fo40225/tensorflow-windows-wheel/blob/master/1.13.1/py37/CPU/sse2/tensorflow-1.13.1-cp37-cp37m-win_amd64.whl) from the repo.

Hope this helps.